# Problems in qt creator

Tags: qt-creator

I have written code in the qt creator on a pc running ubuntu.
After this when I tried to run the same code on another pc using ubuntu, it's not working.

The errors are:

```
MainWindow: no such file or directory
QtGui/QApplication: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of packages you'll need in order to get a Qt application to compile on an Ubuntu machine:

- [build-essential [image: Install build-essential]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential) - *contains `g++`, the GNU C++ compiler and `make` among other things*
- either [libqt4-dev [image: Install libqt4-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libqt4-dev) or [qtbase5-dev [image: Install qtbase5-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/qtbase5-dev) - *contains the headers and libraries needed to compile and link a Qt 4.x or 5.x application*

Assuming the project is using Qmake, run the following commands in the directory containing the `.pro` file:

```
qmake
make
```

Qmake (by default) will read your project file and produce an appropriate makefile for your platform. The second command will build the application from the makefile.